# Eclipse folder structure changed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've searched the web for this information. I created a maven project in Eclipse. all has been working well.  when you look at my project hierarchy I had source folders that looked like: src/main/java and src/main/resources. Within src/main/Java I had com.common.core and com.common.game

I deleted the game directory and my src folder flattened out so the top level is src.  How do I fix that in Eclipse. Now my project does not compile because my  import is com.common.core.file  How do I get the folder to look like src/main/java

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to alter the Maven source directory, just have you tried to recreate that package?

Comment: I had src/main/java land src/main/resources  Then I had under src/main/java   com.common.core and com.common.game   I selected game folder and deleted... then the src/main/java flattened out to where only the src folder was shown! If I expanded src I see main and then java then com then common then core then all my files, but the project won't compile

Comment: I read the question. No need to explain the problem again. Again, why can't you recreate the package you deleted? I think a screenshot of your project structure would be better than an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Project -> Properties -> Build path

Add and remove the source folders to follow your new structure.

Comment: now I see the src/main/java folder but I don't see the com.common.core where the java files are... That directory and files are on my file system. How do I get them to show up under the src/main/java folder

Comment: well Ive got the src/main/java fixed and works.. but I can't get the src/test/java folder does is messed up. when I go to build path and try to link the source to src/test/java the folder I select is put at the same level as sr/test/java.....

Comment: Still lost:  my SRC folder (at the top level of the project) only goes one level deep in the hierarchy!  The Build path folders  src/main/resources is correct. I can navigate the hierarchy and see the resource files.  src/main/java  and src/test/java are flat nothing to navigate?  If you look at the directories outside of eclipse the hierarchy and java files are all there.  How can I fix this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Package Presentation setting

EDIT: Also, keep in mind that the Package Presentation setting (set from the view's local menu--the upside down triangle) might be different between the Project and Package Explorer views. Adjust as you see fit if things look the opposite of how you'd like.